# good site and impressive design ... how to subscribe to notifications?

Tags: discussion

This is a good SharePoint site. I am very impressed the amount of information available on this web site about SharePoint. The site design is very impressive. The site performance is good too. Is there anyway I can subscribe to articles notification via email please?

Answer (score 1):

In the bottom right corner, there is an RSS feed labeled "Question Feed".  Email does not appear to be an option at this point in time.

Answer (score 1):

You can also subscribe to [specific tags via email](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/subscribe-to-tags-via-emai/).

The easiest way is just to hover over a particular tag and click the "subscribe" link.